# What does this html tag mean in django's example?

Tags: django

This is django's polls demo, and most are well documented. However, in this part:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/intro/tutorial04/

```
<h1>{{ question.question_text }}</h1>

<ul>
{% for choice in question.choice_set.all %}
    <li>{{ choice.choice_text }} -- {{ choice.votes }} vote{{ choice.votes|pluralize }}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>

<a href="{% url 'polls:detail' question.id %}">Vote again?</a>
```

The documentation doesn't say anything about this part:

```
vote{{ choice.votes|pluralize }}
```

And from the generated html page, I can't see what's the role of this piece?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pluralize is an in-built Django template tag that attempts to convert the word that it is appended to to plural.  So you feed it a number, and if the number is 1 then it returns '', but if the number is greater than 1, it returns 's'.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#pluralize